# Using foreach to update fields in a mysql database based on another query

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have to do a first query which is `SELECT * from table WHERE NOT column=0`, and use the results from that to do a foreach loop something like below.

```
foreach($results as $result) { 
$nox = $result[field_x]; 
//Use nox for whatever; 
//Then update some fields in SQL; }
```

And keep doing that until all the items in the first query are done.

What would the syntax be?

Comment: jesus christ dont tempt me, it would be just too easy to close the lid on the laptop right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `column` = 0";

// query the database
$resource = mysql_query($sql);

// loop through the results
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
    // grab the value
    $nox = $result['field_x'];   // you should use quotes here, btw

    // make your modifications;
    ++$nox; // or whatever

    // build the query
    $sql = sprintf(
        "UPDATE `myTable` SET `field_x` = %d WHERE `id` = %d"
        , $nox
        , $result['id']
    );

    // run the query
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, Im really not being lazy or stupid, im just lazy, stupid and tired after a long day!

Comment: basic I know but the start would be:
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT field_x=0";
    $results = mysql_query($query);
right?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some extensive processing done in PHP you can most likely do that in a single, [multi-table UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html).

For example:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
   SET t1.col = t2.col + 1
 WHERE t1.somecol <> 0
```

Comment: it really is extensive php processing! thats why i wanted to make sure my way of thinking was alright. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You'd just use a simple `update` command:

```
update tbl set field = '$value' where id = $id
```

In PHP-ese:

```
$sql = 'update tbl set field = \'' .
        mysql_real_escape_string($value) . '\' where id = ' . $id;
mysql_query($sql);
```